# Product of two columns correct at the row level but the total is wrong

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a report with the following columns.

GLG Stock Units is a measure.
Stock Value MP should be [GLG Stock Units] * [Item Standard Cost].

As you can see it works at the row level, but the total looks so wrong. I am not sure what the issue with the formula for [Stock Value MP]?

[image]

Here is the calculation for [Stock Value MP]
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to include your DAX expression for `GLG Stock Units` measure.

Comment: GLG Stock Units = 
CALCULATE(
    [Stock Units (All)],
    'Dim Location'[Location Code]="GLG"
)

Answer (score 0):

`PRODUCTX` multiplies all rows in the expression. At the row level, `[Item Standard Cost]` will simply be the same (since it has row context) - **but** for the total, it will be multiplying all rows of `[Item Standard Cost]` together, to give you that very large number.

I believe you are simply wanting:

```
Stock Value MP = SUMX('Dim Item', 'Dim Item'[Item Standard Cost] * [GLG Stock Units])
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?